# Drawing critical points together with a level curve

Tags: graphing-functions

I would like some help sketching the critical points of a given function.

The function $f$ is given by
$f (x, y) = (\sin x + \sin y)^2$ for all $(x, y)$ in $\mathbb R^2$.

The critical points we have gotten so far are:
$(((π/2)+2πn),(π/2)+2πn)$, $((π/2)+ 2πn,(3π/2)+2πn)$,
$((π/2) + πn, (π/2) + 2πn)$, $((3π/2) + 2πn, (π/2) + 2nπ)$, $((π/2)*πn, (3π/2)*2πn)$.

The conclusion I've made from this is that they either should be multiples of $π/2$, or be on the line $y = -x$.

Now I would want to get help drawing the critical points together with the level curve $ f(x,y) = 0 $.

Comment: You can use the comand "\sin". It's more elegant ;)

Comment: You can use wolfram alpha for help: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+f(x,y)+%3D+(sin+x+%2B+sin+y)%5E2, https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin+x+%2B+sin+y+%3D+0+for+-5+%3C%3D+x+%3C%3D+5,+-5+%3C%3D+y+%3C%3D+5

Comment: @Moo Yes, but the problem is that it should be sketched together with the level curve f(x, y) = 0.

Comment: @levap Yes, but the problem is that it should be sketched together with the level curve f(x, y) = 0.

Comment: @Moo Yes, I got to that curve as well, but I am supposed to realize this without some plotting program. I need some help motivating why that curve is the correct one, algebraically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by drawing the level curve $f(x,y) = \sin x + \sin y = 0$. Note that for a fixed $x_0$, to find the points $(x_0, y)$ that satisfy $f(x_0,y) = 0$, we need to solve $\sin y = -\sin x_0$. Thus,

$$ y = \arcsin( -\sin x_0) + 2\pi k = - \arcsin( \sin x_0 ) + 2\pi k = -x_0 + 2\pi k $$

or

$$ y = \pi - \arcsin( -\sin x_0) + 2\pi l = x_0 + \pi(2l + 1) $$

where $k, l \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Thus,

$$ f^{-1}(0) = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \{ (x, -x + 2\pi k) \, | \, x \in \mathbb{R} \} \cup \bigcup_{l \in \mathbb{Z}} \{ (x, x + \pi(2l + 1) \, | \, x \in \mathbb{R} \} = \\
\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \{ y = -x + 2\pi k \} \cup \bigcup_{l \in \mathbb{Z}} \{ y = x + \pi (2l + 1) \} $$

is the union of infinitely many pairwise parallel lines $y = -x + 2\pi k$ together with infinitely many pairwise parallel lines $y = x + \pi (2l + 1)$ that intersect the lines $y = -x + 2\pi k$ at right angles. The union forms a grid depicted [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20(sin%20x%20%2B%20sin%20y)%20%3D%200%20for%20-5%20%3C%3D%20x%20%3C%3D%205,%20-5%20%3C%3D%20y%20%3C%3D%205) that divides the plane into squares whose edges are of length $\sqrt{2} \pi$. Along the grid, the function has a (global) minimum.

Then, add to your picture the critical points $ \left( \frac{\pi}{2} + \pi k, \frac{\pi}{2} + \pi l \right)$ which are the global maxima of your function. Each point will be the middle point of each of the squares depicted above.